# Wordpress - Customise Search Query

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect, search

I'm running the latest Wordpress with WooCommerce

I'm trying to customise my search results when I use the search bar in the header of my site.

This is how the results appear when doing a normal search:

```
http://www.sunshinetrading.com/snowmasters/?s=snow
```

This is how they **should** appear, when I search through WooCommerce.

```
http://www.sunshinetrading.com/snowmasters/?s=snow&post_type=product
```

What I need to do is automatically append `&post_type=product` onto every search query launched from the header.

My attempts at a solution:

I added this to my child theme's `functions.php` file, to try and append the query which would fix everything.

```
// Search WooCommerce

function search_filter($query) {
    if ( !is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        if ($query->is_search) {
            echo esc_url( add_query_arg( 'post_type', 'product' ) );
            $query->set('post_type', 'product');
        }
    }
}

add_action('pre_get_posts','search_filter');
```

However, when I do this, and do a search, what the URL *should be* appears briefly as text on the page, before the website proceeds to load exactly the same page as before.

What am I doing wrong? Maybe I could solve this problem by editing the `.htaccess` file. I've added the following ...

```
# REWRITE SNOWMASTERS SEARCH
RedirectMatch 302 snowmasters.com.au/?s=(.*) http://snowmasters.com.au/?s=$1&post_type=product
```

This should redirect http://snowmasters.com.au/?s=snow to http://snowmasters.com.au/?s=snow&post_type=product

But it's not working?

I would appreciate your help Stack Overflow community :)

Thanks

Comment: I'm trying now to get mod_apache to redirect the user, through the .htaccess file. See changes above.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this function already?

```
add_query_arg( 'post_type', 'product', 'http://www.sunshinetrading.com/' );
```

You can also register you query string var in wordpress like this:

```
   function add_query_vars_filter( $qVars ){
   $qVars[] = "post_type";
   return $qVars;
   }
   add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );
```

This is from the codex: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/query_vars

Comment: Thanks Carlos - unfortunately that doesn't seem to work.